# Template interface - to use by reference or by value

Tags: c++, templates, interface, reference

I have a template interface

```
template <typename Graph, typename V>
size_t bfs(const Graph& g, const V s, const V x);
```

Where type V is the name of a vertex. It's expected that it would be a simple type to copy, (any primitive), but nothing is stopping the user from using `std::string` as the name.

With a reference, 8 bytes (64 bit) is copied and extra work has to be done to dereference it. This is compared to 4 bytes with no extra work for the usual case of `int` or `size_t` for naming vertices.

Should the interface be `const V&` or just `const V`?

Answer (score 2):

Any deduced parameter which you *may* need to copy in an implementation shall be passed by value (adding `const` is pointless, though: it doesn't change the interface but restricts the implementation). The primary reason is: if a user wants/needs to give the parameter reference semantics and it is passed by value it can be done easily, e.g., by passing `std::ref(x)`. However, once an entity is passed by reference (which includes all three forms `T&`, `T const&`, and `T&&`) it can't be made to have value behavior.